# Are there any selenium locators present which can scrape any content of a webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently i use `Python` with `selenium` for scraping purpose. There are many ways in `selenium` to scrape data. And I used to use `css selectors`.

But then I realised that,
Only `tagNames` are those things which always are on websites. 
For example,

Not every website uses classes or Id's like, take an example of Wikipedia. They use normally just tags in it. 
like `<h1>`, `<a>` without having any classes or id in it.

There comes the limitation for scraping USING `tagNames`, as they scrape every element under their tags.

For example : if I want to scrape table contents which are under `<p>` tag, then it scrapes the table contents as well as all the descriptions which are not needed.

My question is: is it possible to scrape the required elements under the tags which do not copy every other elements under their tags?

Like if I want to scrape content from, say Amazon then it will select only product names under `h1` tags, not scraping all the headings under the `h1` tag which are not product names.

If you find any other method/locator to use, even except the tagName also then also you can tell me. But the condition is that it must be present on every website/ most of the websites

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to scrape the elements of most of the websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052512/is-there-a-better-way-to-scrape-the-elements-of-most-of-the-websites)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answered my question... That's why I asked again.

Comment: Also the question is bit different.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is generally yes, unless you are working on the Halting Problem or similar. The answer to "how is it possible" highly depends on what you are trying to do exactly, what your constraints are, what restrictions can be assumed, and so on. Please provide more focus to your question so that it is possible to say what exactly an adequate answer is.

Comment: Okay should I ask another question focusing as more practically and not theoretically ?? If you are saying, that it's possible then I surely put another question on it.